# How are cells deselected programmatically in UICollectionView when allowMultipleSelection is enabled?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have allowMultipleSelection enabled in a collection view. The cells change to and from their 
 selected states when tapped. All good. However, when I want to reset the entire view to selected state:NO using the code below, the cells appears to be entirely deselected until I then make a new selection, at which point all previously selected cells show their previously selected state.

i.e. despite appearances the collectionview is not updating it's current selection list when I programmatically deselect the cells

```
- (void)clearCellSelections {
   for (LetterCell  *cell in self.collectionView.visibleCells) {
        [cell prepareForReuse];
    }
}
```

In custom cell:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];
    [self setSelected:NO];
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to deselect all cells?

Thanks TBlue for taking a look

Comment: Refresh the collectionview control?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can iterate over `- [UICollectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]`:

```
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]) {
    [self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Small correction. There is an `animated` parameter. Thus it should be: `[self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];`

Comment: Edited for animated parameter.

Comment: You also need self.collectionView.reloadData()

Comment: Without reloadData() only the visible cells will be updated.

Comment: @Scooter Can you show me the way? I didn't get any effect.

Answer (score 22):

The simplest way to deselect all selected cells in a `UICollectionView` is simply to pass `nil` as the first argument to `collectionView.selectItem(at:, animated:, scrollPosition:)`.  E.g.,

```
collectionView.selectItem(at: nil, animated: true, scrollPosition: [])
```

will clear the current selection state, even when `allowsMultipleSelection == true`.

Comment: This is a much better, more concise answer. I think however you still need to iterate over cells if you want to deselect all cells in a section (and leave the other sections untouched).

Comment: Short and simple answer

Answer (score 11):

You could say that `UITableViewCell.selected` only sets the 'visible state/appearance' of the cell and it's contents. You could deselect the cells, by iterating over all indexPaths of the tableView and call `deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:` for each one.

For instance:

```
for (int i=0; i < self.myData.count; i++) {
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0] animated:YES];
}
```

**EDIT**: I totally agree with @BenLings and @JeremyWiebe's comments, that @qorkfiend's solution is preferred over this one.

Comment: @ fguchelaar how to make it work in UICollectionView. It is not working there. I tried this way  [self.collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0]];

Comment: @qorkfiend's answer is preferable to this one

Comment: Agree with @BenLings especially when your data set is large.  With this solution you have to enumerate every single item, which gets worse if you are using an NSFetchedResultsController with Core Data.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case this is simple solution in Swift:

```
extension UICollectionView {
    func deselectAllItems(animated animated: Bool = false) {
        for indexPath in self.indexPathsForSelectedItems() ?? [] {
            self.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: animated)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For swift 3 Extension would looks like this:

```
import UIKit

extension UICollectionView {
    func deselectAllItems(animated: Bool = false) {
        for indexPath in self.indexPathsForSelectedItems ?? [] {
            self.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: animated)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is complete if you want to delegate also be called

```
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in [self.cuisineCollection indexPathsForSelectedItems]) {
            [self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
            [collectionView.delegate collectionView:cuisineCollection didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a global variable called toggleCellSelection, then ran this in the didSelectItemAt function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("select cell \(indexPath.row)")

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    if (toggleCellSelection == true) {
        toggleCellSelection = false
        cell?.layer.borderWidth = 0
        cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear().cgColor
    } else {
        toggleCellSelection = true
        cell?.layer.borderWidth = 5
        cell?.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8779790998, green: 0.3812967837, blue: 0.5770481825, alpha: 1).cgColor
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that this answer is the necessarily 'the best', but since no one mentioned it, I'll add it.

You can simply call the following.

```
collectionView.allowsSelection = false
collectionView.allowsSelection = true
```

Answer (score 0):

This is @qorkfiend answer in Swift

```
// this is an array of the selected item(s) indexPaths
guard let indexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems else { return }

// loop through the array and individually deselect each item
for indexPath in indexPaths{
    collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```